# Firewall rules Tor Middle Relay help

Tags: relays, onion-routing, openbsd

**ORPort 9001**

From external from the **entry relays** to internal the traffic runs

**inet proto tcp port >1024 to --> port 9001**

... but, then for my understanding:

How runs the traffic out from here **(the middle relay)** to the next exit relay?

Stand on the line right now :)

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All relays must accept all inbound connections to their chosen ORPort and must allow outbound connections to any valid internet-routable address and port combination, as any other internet server on any valid TCP port could be a relay.

It's worth noting that all relays are potentially valid for all positions, what positions clients use them in is determined by flags that they are given by votes from the Directory Authorities. There are no "guard", "middle" or "exit" relays.

The only position you can effectively opt-out of is the exit, but it's not that you're a "non-exit", you just have a policy that doesn't allow any exiting.

Answer (score 0):

You must use **exact** port number at firewall forwarding rule : Tor announces it's ORPort as a number from config. And if it's behind a firewall - it's ok, it will detect *the IP address*, but the port is not detected - it is used "as is". And you need to forward like this all the ports from your torrc: ORPort, DirPort and bridge port(s) - use same numbers. No extra/temporary ports used, like in FTP for example : only the ones you've specified